# Remote debugging a Windows Service VS2010

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010

I have developed a windows service on my system and have deployed the service on a target machine which does not have visual studio. Therefore, I need to debug the application from my PC. I already know how to debug a windows service on a local machine.

**MY STEPS:**

1. Copied the complete bin folder (containing .exe as well as .pdb files) to the target machine.
2. Installed the service on the target machine using `InstallUtil.exe` (i.e `installUtil.exe "pathToMyServiceEXE/myService.Exe"`)
3. Started the service
4. Installed Visual Studio Remote Debugging application (started in "No Authentication mode" with Debugging option checked)
5. Attached to the service in Visual Studio (which is running on my PC)

**PROBLEM:** I am able to successfully attached to the windows service of the target machine. ***But it cannot find the symbols.***

I have checked other SO questions about the same problem but could not find the correct solution so far. ***I have tried the following things to solve the problem:***

- Opened `Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols` and then put the path of .pdb files on my local PC. (Didn't work)
- Opened `Tools->Options->Debugging->General` and unchecked "Enable just my code".
- In addition to above two, I have already made sure that I am running the x64 version of the Remote debugging tool, Debug/x64 version of windows service and debug/x64 on my local PC.

Comment: Maybe debug from your window service source in VS + deployed `appconfig`

Comment: Let the debugger tell you.  Debug > Windows > Modules, locate a module that you want to debug in the displayed list.  Right-click and select Symbol Load Information.  Tells you where it looked for the PDB file.

Comment: @HansPassant: I already did that but it says that the .pdb file is not valid. I think that the problem is because my application is in Managed Code and I have started the Remote Debugging for Native only. I should start the Remote Debugging tool in "Windows Authentication Mode", which I did but then I am not able to login into it.

Comment: Well, that is not going to work of course.  Very hard to guess why you would even consider trying to do this and thought it unnecessary to not mention it in the question.  Makes no sense at all.

Comment: @HansPassant: I am trying to do the Remote Debugging for the first time and was not completely familiar with the tool. When I posted the question, I didn't know that these two modes are for different kind of codes (I thought that its just for security purposes). And now I am stuck at the problem of  getting logged-in to the Windows Authentication Mode.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice that I can give you - which is not the easiest now, but will pay off in the long run - is to use WinDBG debugger on the target machine. This is next to zero setup on the target machine but will require you to learn the basics of WinDBG. This is not trivial but will pay off in the long run.

Regarding why you cannot load symbols:

1. Maybe PDBs do not match binaries?
2. Maybe path is not accesible to the current logged-in user? (such as mapped drive, etc)
3. Maybe permission issue?

Other then that I think it should work

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Can you suggest any tutorial or something....whatever I have found so far, I couldn't understand how would it help me to debug the remote mahchine application

Comment: WinDBG is the most powerful debugger I know but it has its own pitfalls. It is the best because it can do mostly any debugging task you will need and it has next to zero footprint in means of size and setup, but it has its own pitfalls because it is a cryptic tool and it does require a learning curve.

Comment: When learning how to use WinDBG I would recommend on:
a. Learn how to setup the symbol environment (.symfix, .sympath and .srcpath),
b. Type '.hh' and ENTER in order to reach the HELP console,
c. Google how to do a particular debugging task with WinDBG
Doing this will most likely mean that in order to solve your particular problem here it will take you longer as you are learning a new tool but most likely that the next time you will need to debug something on 'customer environment' you will prefer to use WinDBG considering its advantages.